# lookup table_array argument increments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bit of a dilemma in regards to the vlookup table array increments. In other words within the vlookup formula  `=VLOOKUP($Q$3,S:T,2,FALSE)` when I pull the formula to the right I would like the table array to go to columns `U:V` not `T:U`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: And what about the lookup_value? What should this become, when dragged to the right? Q3? R3? S3?

Comment: The lookup value is absolute ,it douse not change

Comment: In your given formula it is not absolute.

Comment: The lookup value is irelevet the actual formula that I am using is a lot longer this vlookup bit is the only thing that douse not do what I want, like I mentioned I wold like to know if it’s possible to change the tabble_array increments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue to use `VLOOKUP`, though the required set-up is `volatile`:

`=VLOOKUP($Q3,OFFSET($S:$T,0,2*(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)),2,FALSE)`

Preferable is to switch to a non-volatile `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

`=INDEX($S:$XFD,MATCH($Q3,$S:$S,0),2*COLUMNS($A:A))`

Regards

Comment: Thank yo for your response and yes you are right in assuming that v lookup is volatile but It was a ‘quick fix’ I will try you solution and get back to you.

Comment: VLOOKUP is NOT volatile. OFFSET is.

Comment: I know but INDEX MATCH Causes a few problemes when combine with the rest of my formula . Regardless I will see if I can work around it.

Comment: I did the modifications and they did the trick wonderfully thank you for the help.